# How to hide QML Debugging warning

Tags: qt-creator

> QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.

I'm working on a test software in Python for a Qt Creator project which need to use the QML Debugging. The python software is running the built project and test its features. I would like to actually hide that message without disabling the QML debug. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify

```
DEFINES += QT_QML_DEBUG_NO_WARNING
```

in the .pro file to disable the warning.