# How to disable specific QML debugger warning

Tags: qt, qml, suppress-warnings

I don't want to disable all warnings from QML ([as asked in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37996105/qt-hide-qml-debugging-warning)). Instead I want to disable a specific type of warning. In my case the `TypeError: Cannot read property of null` warning.

Note that I am getting this warning as a result of a [Qt bug that affects grandchildren elements during their destruction](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57650), not as a result of any code errors, I believe. In my case, I get lots of these warnings (10s to 100s) each time a particular `GridView` model is changed, so these messages are dominating the console log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a high level solution would probably be based on installing custom message handler and intercept all warnings, filter out any warning you like ***to deal with in a different way*** and bypass others, this for example can handle your case:

```
// Default message handler to be called to bypass all other warnings.
static const QtMessageHandler QT_DEFAULT_MESSAGE_HANDLER = qInstallMessageHandler(0);
// a custom message handler to intercept warnings
void customMessageHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString & msg)
{
    switch (type) {
    case QtWarningMsg: {
        if (!msg.contains("TypeError: Cannot read property of null")){ // suppress this warning
            (*QT_DEFAULT_MESSAGE_HANDLER)(type, context, msg); // bypass and display all other warnings
        }
    }
    break;
    default:    // Call the default handler.
        (*QT_DEFAULT_MESSAGE_HANDLER)(type, context, msg);
        break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    qInstallMessageHandler(customMessageHandler); // install custom msg handler
...
}
```

Comment: That is both a beautiful and a horrible solution. Beautiful because the code is clear and it works perfectly. Horrible because it involves altering the project. Thank you! I'll use it until the Qt bug is resolved.